# fb.me and ajaxCrawling

Tags: ajax, facebook, web-crawler

With the FB url shortner (fb.me) the `#ajaxCrawling` do not work properly as in Facebook. 
Probably the mistake could be mine but when i share a content with an exclamation mark after the `#` sign, Facebook exposes to the user the url with `escaped_fragment` instead of the normal one.

eg.
if you try to share this url with fb.me,

http://www.mamamo.it/#!/content/app/little-red-riding-hood-di-nosy-crow

facebook displays this one to the user:

http://www.mamamo.it/?_escaped_fragment_=%2Fcontent%2Fapp%2Flittle-red-riding-hood-di-nosy-crow (it's wrong)

how to solve it ?